# Why Are Some Foreign Characters Not Displaying Properly

Tags: unreal-4, blueprints, localization

I am localizing a game for the first time and I'm noticing some characters are not displaying properly. Most are fine but there is a small handful that are not correct. For example on a loading screen I display the word Loading. In German I'm displaying `Lädt`. The `ä` character is not displayed as `ä`, instead isn't displayed as shown in the image. I'm running in a standalone game. I packaged a development build to see if the problem was there too but it seem localizing is not working when I package it but I can tackle that problem later unless there is a known issues with this. To change languages I am calling Set Current Culture in blueprints.

[image]

Comment: Does your font support non-ascii characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this is because of the font I'm using. It doesn't support some of the characters used in other languages. The answer to my question on UE4's answer [hub has](https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/748400/why-are-some-foreign-characters-not-displaying-pro.html) more details.